# Weird position bug in Unity 4.6 for prefab gameobject as child of Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am putting a prefab (basically an Image) onto a Canvas at "0,0,0" in a script (for debug sake). When I press play in the editor, this is carried out but the GameObject end up at "-3.051758e-05,-280,0" i.e. way off from 0,0,0. What could cause this?

The Canvas is a child of the root canvas and is set to max out its size in order to be as big as its parent.

Using Unity 4.6.

Update: Not 100% sure yet but when setting position using `somegameobject.localPosition = somevector` the positioning seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform.localPosition` sets the position relative to the parents position whereas `transform.position` sets the position in worldspace. If you take a look at the canvas in scene view you will see that the bottom left corner of the canvas will be at `0, 0, 0` in worldspace, but `0, 0, 0` of the canvas is in its center. Since you have to instantiate a gameobject first and make it a child afterwards, it's position in worldspace is `0, 0, 0`, but it's position in the inspector is its position relative to its parents position and will therefor not be `0, 0, 0` since the canvas doesn't sit a `0, 0, 0`.

Setting the child with `localPosition` after instantiating will position it the way you want it relative to the canvas. `0, 0, 0` will then be in the center of the game view. The position of the child in worldspace would then be `canvas.x, canvas.y, 0` (you won't see that in the inspector of course).

Comment: Thanks, what's really putting me in the wrong direction from the beginning is the Unity editor interface. The position in Recttransform in the Unity editor is NOT the same as somegameobject.transform.position in code. They ought to do something about that :-P On the other hand, I think there are just a few rare cases where you need a global position of a 2D element that sits inside some other element. Normally the position I need is the local position.